# Obtain Specific Column From Correlation Heatmap

Tags: r

I have a dataset called allDataNoNAs which has 19 columns for different variables.

First, using the packages:

```
library(corrplot)
library(corrgram)
library(GGally)
```

From dput(cor(allDataNoNAs) - my sample correlation

```
structure(c(1, 0.116349634765185, 0.547691763989625, 0.291991636906379, 
0.52347996305183, 0.497643100595069, 0.0129815335193983, 0.418358158731718, 
0.471373794854162, 0.505419557447448, 0.276128001065287, 0.114921357444725, 
0.483335903285957, 0.0322484793148408, 0.360658177617753, 0.163989166178892, 
0.145358618474009, 0.549222657694447, 0.0283182668409127, 0.116349634765185, 
1, 0.542678597132992, 0.228195095236888, 0.341733815370385, 0.449234592784623, 
0.040928188236085, 0.306532564182676, 0.246214540314882, 0.368735099181333, 
0.0974107116463065, 0.118633970020044, 0.0663374870504325, 0.00324065971750887, 
0.429993810524071, 0.0660128392326907, -0.208834964557656, 0.517351517191311, 
0.00340750071414792, 0.547691763989625, 0.542678597132992, 1, 
0.503509567685111, 0.834074832294578, 0.87458120333133, 0.11646402536793, 
0.709723789822138, 0.545685105436571, 0.691116703644981, 0.251055925294139, 
0.137145560677364, 0.677547477041307, 0.0138408591129587, 0.574449939471671, 
0.289088705565296, -0.0151310469001056, 0.995636799856898, 0.00806307965229721, 
0.291991636906379, 0.228195095236888, 0.503509567685111, 1, 0.5928306942291, 
0.419860437848609, 0.202947501799892, 0.600369342626932, 0.3036531414462, 
0.31218278418869, 0.0665676462597262, 0.0706549436236251, 0.463190217918095, 
0.017439704947323, 0.20361820902537, 0.563054610829996, 0.367022482937022, 
0.539278002253207, 0.0146950545295136, 0.52347996305183, 0.341733815370385, 
0.834074832294578, 0.5928306942291, 1, 0.877884027429435, 0.249913906532112, 
0.770346073267575, 0.581478562237408, 0.62684315599784, 0.158950811299692, 
0.0709795609883571, 0.707727230043996, 0.0374999988906861, 0.36979003972634, 
0.532230871495189, 0.237891979696682, 0.868052149324532, 0.0301272383779361, 
0.497643100595069, 0.449234592784623, 0.87458120333133, 0.419860437848609, 
0.877884027429435, 1, 0.0578337272432955, 0.625271696806798, 
0.642882384190134, 0.742158234646655, 0.18412573265697, 0.0846354163480033, 
0.636899685921357, 0.00136017420567482, 0.442530075276962, 0.166101818463978, 
-0.122330359121607, 0.870582759035652, -0.00536057317986459, 
0.0129815335193983, 0.040928188236085, 0.11646402536793, 0.202947501799892, 
0.249913906532112, 0.0578337272432955, 1, 0.168170227241747, 
0.0103942343836554, 0.0146416101891029, 0.0274638568337838, 0.0232209281980358, 
0.438976017479895, 0.00664290788845518, 0.0558346558356874, 0.576321333713829, 
0.205483416691572, 0.160939456560856, 0.00633413505889225, 0.418358158731718, 
0.306532564182676, 0.709723789822138, 0.600369342626932, 0.770346073267575, 
0.625271696806798, 0.168170227241747, 1, 0.421695218774506, 0.481156860252289, 
0.109952341757847, 0.0400601095104961, 0.560225169205313, 0.0470119529030615, 
0.311744196849895, 0.445382213345548, 0.237447342653341, 0.743416109744227, 
0.0437634515476897, 0.471373794854162, 0.246214540314882, 0.545685105436571, 
0.3036531414462, 0.581478562237408, 0.642882384190134, 0.0103942343836554, 
0.421695218774506, 1, 0.809375500184827, 0.201944501698817, 0.098871956246993, 
0.46496436444905, -0.00410066612855966, 0.34093890132072, 0.0955588133868073, 
-0.0561387410393148, 0.542950578488189, -0.00611403179202383, 
0.505419557447448, 0.368735099181333, 0.691116703644981, 0.31218278418869, 
0.62684315599784, 0.742158234646655, 0.0146416101891029, 0.481156860252289, 
0.809375500184827, 1, 0.166272569833104, 0.0642480288154233, 
0.493094322495752, -0.0143825404077684, 0.420509020130084, 0.0763222806834054, 
-0.137267266981321, 0.675599964220607, -0.0155210421858565, 0.276128001065287, 
0.0974107116463065, 0.251055925294139, 0.0665676462597262, 0.158950811299692, 
0.18412573265697, 0.0274638568337838, 0.109952341757847, 0.201944501698817, 
0.166272569833104, 1, 0.803405447808051, 0.209386276142885, 0.019611871344881, 
0.698294870666248, 0.024793538949468, 0.00921044459805193, 0.243573446480239, 
0.0182042685108301, 0.114921357444725, 0.118633970020044, 0.137145560677364, 
0.0706549436236251, 0.0709795609883571, 0.0846354163480033, 0.0232209281980358, 
0.0400601095104961, 0.098871956246993, 0.0642480288154233, 0.803405447808051, 
1, 0.0518698024423593, 0.0195654257050434, 0.534756730460756, 
0.00851489725348713, -0.00157091125920201, 0.131294046914676, 
0.0196406046872536, 0.483335903285957, 0.0663374870504325, 0.677547477041307, 
0.463190217918095, 0.707727230043996, 0.636899685921357, 0.438976017479895, 
0.560225169205313, 0.46496436444905, 0.493094322495752, 0.209386276142885, 
0.0518698024423593, 1, 0.00595760440442105, 0.332127234258051, 
0.402991372365854, 0.130619402830307, 0.702714128886842, 0.000759081836999778, 
0.0322484793148408, 0.00324065971750887, 0.0138408591129587, 
0.017439704947323, 0.0374999988906861, 0.00136017420567482, 0.00664290788845518, 
0.0470119529030615, -0.00410066612855966, -0.0143825404077684, 
0.019611871344881, 0.0195654257050434, 0.00595760440442105, 1, 
0.0240839070381978, 0.0543455541899934, 0.121224926189405, 0.0181415673103803, 
0.999560527964641, 0.360658177617753, 0.429993810524071, 0.574449939471671, 
0.20361820902537, 0.36979003972634, 0.442530075276962, 0.0558346558356874, 
0.311744196849895, 0.34093890132072, 0.420509020130084, 0.698294870666248, 
0.534756730460756, 0.332127234258051, 0.0240839070381978, 1, 
0.101917219961389, -0.0673808764564209, 0.55786516587572, 0.0226512629105265, 
0.163989166178892, 0.0660128392326907, 0.289088705565296, 0.563054610829996, 
0.532230871495189, 0.166101818463978, 0.576321333713829, 0.445382213345548, 
0.0955588133868073, 0.0763222806834054, 0.024793538949468, 0.00851489725348713, 
0.402991372365854, 0.0543455541899934, 0.101917219961389, 1, 
0.562085375561417, 0.360237027957389, 0.0519977244267395, 0.145358618474009, 
-0.208834964557656, -0.0151310469001056, 0.367022482937022, 0.237891979696682, 
-0.122330359121607, 0.205483416691572, 0.237447342653341, -0.0561387410393148, 
-0.137267266981321, 0.00921044459805193, -0.00157091125920201, 
0.130619402830307, 0.121224926189405, -0.0673808764564209, 0.562085375561417, 
1, 0.041068964081757, 0.119487910165712, 0.549222657694447, 0.517351517191311, 
0.995636799856898, 0.539278002253207, 0.868052149324532, 0.870582759035652, 
0.160939456560856, 0.743416109744227, 0.542950578488189, 0.675599964220607, 
0.243573446480239, 0.131294046914676, 0.702714128886842, 0.0181415673103803, 
0.55786516587572, 0.360237027957389, 0.041068964081757, 1, 0.0121897372730556, 
0.0283182668409127, 0.00340750071414792, 0.00806307965229721, 
0.0146950545295136, 0.0301272383779361, -0.00536057317986459, 
0.00633413505889225, 0.0437634515476897, -0.00611403179202383, 
-0.0155210421858565, 0.0182042685108301, 0.0196406046872536, 
0.000759081836999778, 0.999560527964641, 0.0226512629105265, 
0.0519977244267395, 0.119487910165712, 0.0121897372730556, 1), .Dim = c(19L, 
19L), .Dimnames = list(c("RPE", "Duration", "Distance", "Max Speed", 
"HML Distance", "HML Efforts", "Sprint Distance", "Sprints", 
"Accelerations", "Decelerations", "Average Heart Rate", "Max Heart Rate", 
"Average Metabolic Power", "Dynamic Stress Load", "Heart Rate Exertion", 
"High Speed Running (Relative)", "HML Density", "Speed Intensity", 
"Impacts"), c("RPE", "Duration", "Distance", "Max Speed", "HML Distance", 
"HML Efforts", "Sprint Distance", "Sprints", "Accelerations", 
"Decelerations", "Average Heart Rate", "Max Heart Rate", "Average Metabolic Power", 
"Dynamic Stress Load", "Heart Rate Exertion", "High Speed Running (Relative)", 
"HML Density", "Speed Intensity", "Impacts")))
```

Using the correlation data from above, I am trying to just obtain the first column where I see the correlation between RPE and all other 18 variables. I can do this by doing `cor(allDataNoNAs)[,1]` but then when I try and plot that as a correlogram using `corrplot(corrgram(allDataNoNAs))[,1]` it plots all 19x19 correlations and is a mess, when I just need the RPE correlation column.

Using `ggcorr()` as such:

```
ggcorr(allDataNoNAs, method = c("everything"), label = TRUE,label_size = 2, label_round = 4)
```

I obtain the cleaner looking heatmap that I want. But, switching the `data` parameter to `allDataNoNAs[,1]` or `cor(allDataNoNAs)[,1]` does not do the trick to only obtain that one RPE correlation column.

Is it possible to only return one column of a correlation heatmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out and answer my own question, though not exactly how I wanted it (wanted it from ggcorr() ), this version suffices, however:

With my same variable names as before

```
#x is the variable you want to be comparing the y variables with
myCorDF <- cor(x = allDataNoNAs$RPE, y = allDataNoNAs[2:19], use = "everything")

#just changing it to colors that seem better to me
col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan", "white",
                           "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))

#this is how I obtain the one column for RPE correlation against other all variables
corrplot(myCorDF, tl.srt = 45, method = "color", addCoef.col = "black", 
         cl.cex = 0.56, col = col2(50))
```

A generic code removing my colors would look like this:

```
corDF <- cor(x = DF$x, y = DF[2:5], use = "everything")

corrplot(corDF, tl.srt = 45, method = "color", addCoef.col = "black", 
         cl.cex = 0.56)
```